# How to get current time in Oracle, and use in interval partition?

Tags: oracle, datetime

I'm trying to create an interval partitioned table in Oracle where the first partition is bounded to a week from now, but I just can't seem to figure out the syntax.

Here's what I have so far..

```
CREATE TABLE TRANSACTION
(
....
, TRANSACTION_DATETIME TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL
....
)
PARTITION BY RANGE(TRANSACTION_DATETIME)
INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(7,'day'))
(PARTITION p_first VALUES LESS THAN (SELECT SYSDATE+7 FROM DUAL));
```

I've tried that and many other variations, such as..

```
(PARTITION p_first VALUES LESS THAN (SYSDATE+7));  //OR
(PARTITION p_first VALUES LESS THAN (SYSDATE+7 FROM DUAL));
```

But none of them seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do that. You need to specify the date yourself, as that clause accepts only literals or `MAXVALUE`, and not expressions.

[image]

So you could just use:

`(PARTITION p_first VALUES LESS THAN (DATE'2015-12-12'));`

If you really want to calculate it dynamically, you need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thanks, what's the name of that clause?

Comment: I just looked up the syntax on the oracle site and it seems to suggest you can use an expression.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/create-table.html

Comment: @RyanStull -- you're looking at the MySQL manual.